# Which Windows Server Supported by MSI 3165NGW AllInOne?

Tags: windows-installation, windows-server, all-in-one

I need to install windows server on my `MSI 3165NGW AllInOne`.

I try to install windows server 2012 R2 but dont detected.

Now Which windows server supported by  `MSI 3165NGW AllInOne`?

Comment: Your device should be able to support any supported version of Windows Server.

Comment: When I place win 10 into DVD drive and restart allInOne it detect windows 10 but when i place windows server 2012 into DVD drive can not detect it and boot screen load auto.

Comment: This DVD drive a USB 3 device?

Comment: No. DVD read/writer

Answer (score 0):

[3165NGW](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Intel_Dual_Band_Wireless-AC_3165_(3165NGW)) is the Intel wifi adapter. It is no existing AiO model from MSI.

But assuming you did the same error of [this advert](https://www.cashconverters.co.uk/shop/product/computer-msi-3165ngw-touchscreen-all-in-one-pc/387365), i.e. you have a Pentium G4xxx, that means Windows Server 2016. Because microsoft's really hell-bent with hardware released after W10.

It's not a hard limit considering drivers and [hacks](https://github.com/zeffy/wufuc) exist nevertheless, but still if it was an out of the box experience that you were aiming that's it.